# Why does the Windows hosts file 'shadow' the PC name when using DNS.GetHostEntry()?

Tags: c#, dns, hosts

Using Windows 10, I renamed my PC to 'ZACH_PC'. I've also edited my hosts file to resolve a dev address to localhost:

```
127.0.0.1 wcf.company.dev
```

This is the only un-commented line in hosts.

In my C# code, I'm using `DNS.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1")`, which as far as I'm aware should return the name of the PC for `HostName`, but is instead returning `wcf.company.dev`.

My (obviously incorrect) understanding of the hosts file is that I can resolve random domain names to an IP address before network requests leave the computer.

But why is GetHostEntry not resolving my localhost address "127.0.0.1" to the name of my PC? It seems like this is resolution is 'backwards', if it looks at the hosts file for an IP address and resolves that to a domain name.

When that entry in the hosts file doesn't exist, the `127.0.0.1` address resolves to my PC name, as I would expect.

Is there an implicit record in 'hosts' that is: `127.0.0.1 <pcname>`?

==== EDIT

In Response to a comment below:

```
IPHostEntry host1 = Dns.GetHostEntry(""); // Gives me the PC name
IPHostEntry host2 = Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")); // Gives me the hosts entry
```

Comment: have you tried flushing your DNS cache for the PC?

Comment: Yes. that did not resolve the problem

Comment: I used to have the reverse problem with WCF, and to fix it, I would add host headers to IIS.  By chance do you already have a host header  specified with that hostname?

Comment: My WCF service is self hosted. I'm changing the question title....

Comment: Localhost is so much fun; Is **NetBIOS** enabled on your computer? What are the results of `DNS.GetHostEntry("")`? or `DNS.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"))`?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've edited the question with the code you provided

Comment: What is NetBIOS? This app is hosted on localhost - on the VPN. Sounds like something I might need to know....